# What is the main usage of MatTestDialogOpener into Angular 15 - Material?

Tags: typescript, testing, angular-material, angular-test

In an Angular developement I am trying to write a test for testing a dialog component. I am quite new with angular testing especially with Material harnessing but I found it very cool.

Here is this dialog component code:

```typescript
export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ResultsComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public questionary: any,
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
   ...
  }
}
```

So I started by reading documentation here :

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#material-dialog-testing-directives

I am interested into using the MatTestDialogOpener directive because, if I understood well, it seems it can wrap my dialog component into a mocked component, so i can test my dialog outside of any parent component context.

My issue is I don't know how to use this directive. I mean, i don't want to add this directive into a template but when i try to init MatTestDialogOpener with TestBed i have an error at creation of ResultsComponent saying:

```
**Error: NG0202:** This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection because its dependency at index 0 of the parameter list is invalid.   
This can happen if the dependency type is a primitive like a string or if an ancestor of this class is missing an Angular decorator.   
Please check that 1) the type for the parameter at index 0 is correct and 2) the correct Angular decorators are defined for this class and its ancestors.
```

It means the dialogRef is not injected to my constructor but it is strange because MatTestDialogOpener has a property named dialogRef. I thinked it would do it automatically.

So my conclusion is, I think I misunderstand the purpose of this directive.

Can you please give me an usage example of this directive in a test context ?

Here is my test init using MatTestDialogOpener:

```typescript
beforeEach(async () => {
    DialogWrapperComponent = MatTestDialogOpener.withComponent(ResultsComponent, { data: questionary });

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        DialogWrapperComponent,
        ResultsComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        SharedModule //Contians MatDialogModule
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DialogWrapperComponent);
    componentWrapper = fixture.componentInstance;
    component = componentWrapper.dialogRef.componentInstance;
    compiled = fixture.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

With this code my ResultsComponent wrapped into MatTestDialogOpener won't init.

I am not especially asking for a method to test my dialog because we already have a lot of answers about this. But I want to understand the purpose of the MatTestDialogOpener and how to use it.

**Framework version:**

Angular 15
Angular Material 15